# Generating daily records from a set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**I have the following query:**

```
SELECT C.DateValue, T.CustomerId, T.Balance
FROM Calendar C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) StartDate, CustomerId, Balance
    FROM TestData B
    WHERE B.StartDate <= C.DateValue
    ORDER BY StartDate DESC
) AS T
WHERE C.DateValue BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/14/2014'
ORDER BY CustomerId, DateValue
```

**That takes a set of data like:**

```
CustomerId | StartDate | EndDate | Balance

123 | 1/1/2014 | 1/3/2014 | 2000
123 | 1/3/2014 | 1/10/2014 | 1000
123 | 1/10/2014 | null | 500
```

**And transforms it into:**

```
CustomerId | Date | Balance

123 | 1/1/2014 | 2000
123 | 1/2/2014 | 2000
123 | 1/3/2014 | 1000
123 | 1/4/2014 | 1000
123 | 1/5/2014 | 1000
...
```

The problem I'm running into is that it only works if there is a single CustomerId. As soon as I add another one to the list. I'm trying to figure out a way to alter this query in a way that supports any number of CustomerIds in the data set. I can accomplish this by using a query such as this:

```
SELECT C.DateValue, T.CustomerId , T.Balance
FROM Calendar C
INNER JOIN TestData T on C.DateValue >= T.DataStartDate
    AND (C.DateValue < T.EndDate OR T.EndDate IS NULL)
WHERE C.DateValue BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/14/2014'
```

But the above query is exceedingly inefficient when I join it to my actual table that contains millions of Customers. *How can I either alter my query or write a query that accomplishes my goal of expanding my data into a daily list?*

**Example Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14320

Comment: So, if I understand, it will ouptut, for this example, more then 14 millions rows...right ?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Actually, the goal is 1 row for every day for every record. So in the above example you'd get 15 days worth of data going from 1/1/2014-1/14/2014. So if you have 2 customers then you get 30 results. If you have 9 million customers then you'd get 135 million results.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Hey, I'm really sorry, I thought that my example spoke for itself. You are definitely pointing me in the right direction and your advice thus far has been immensely helpful. I provided the fiddle as an easy way to interact with my data as closely as possible without actually having it.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14364)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT S.CustomerId, S.DateValue, T.Balance
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId, DateValue
FROM TestData, Calendar
WHERE DateValue BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/14/2014') S
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT TOP(1) Balance
 FROM TestData B
 WHERE B.StartDate <= S.DateValue AND B.CustomerId = S.CustomerId
 ORDER BY StartDate DESC
) AS T
ORDER BY CustomerId, DateValue
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14364/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMERID |  DATEVALUE | BALANCE |
|------------|------------|---------|
|        123 | 2014-01-01 |   25000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-02 |   25000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-03 |   25000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-04 |   25000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-05 |   25000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-06 |   25000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-07 |   20000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-08 |   20000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-09 |   10000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-10 |   10000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-11 |   10000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-12 |   10000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-13 |   10000 |
|        123 | 2014-01-14 |   10000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-01 |   25000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-02 |   25000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-03 |   25000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-04 |   25000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-05 |   25000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-06 |   25000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-07 |   20000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-08 |   20000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-09 |   10000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-10 |   10000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-11 |   10000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-12 |   10000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-13 |   10000 |
|        456 | 2014-01-14 |   10000 |
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as my second query?

Comment: Yep...you're right....I started playing with your 1st query....and it seems that I ended with your second...

Comment: And what about this one ?

Comment: Testing it right now, what concerns me is the distinct call.

Comment: I just added `WHERE DateValue BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/14/2014'` is the `DISTINCT` call (to avoid looking for the entire Calendar table :) )

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query I ended up going with:

```
SELECT C.DateValue, T.CustomerId, T.Balance
FROM Calendar C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT B.CustomerId, B.Balance
    FROM TestData B
    WHERE C.DateValue >= B.StartDate AND (C.DateValue < B.EndDate OR B.EndDate IS NULL)
) AS T
WHERE C.DateValue BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '1/14/2014'
ORDER BY CustomerId, DateValue
```

@BogdanSahlean deserves a lot of the credit for pointing me in the right direction. The key was making sure the `WHERE` clause in the `CROSS APPLY` was tuned properly.

**SQL Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14376